# python get n characters starting from another character from right of string

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
st = "../dir1/dir2/dirN/thisiswhatiwantonlyfirstsevencharacters"
```

I am trying to get the first seven characters starting from the first slash from the right.
Currently I do it manually:

```
st[18:-32]
```

how can i do it by looking up the first slash from right and then get the first seven characters?

Comment: Use `st.split('/')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.rsplit()` and a simple indexing:

```
In [19]: st.rsplit('/', 1)[-1][:7]
Out[19]: 'thisisw'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to split the string, just use `.rfind()` method:

```
st = "../dir1/dir2/dirN/thisiswhatiwantonlyfirstsevencharacters"
last_slash_index = st.rfind('/')
print st[last_slash_index:last_slash_index+8]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
st[st.rfind('/')+1: st.rfind('/')+8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
st = "../dir1/dir2/dirN/thisiswhatiwantonlyfirstsevencharacters"

lst = st.split("/")

output = lst[-1][0:7]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
st = "../dir1/dir2/dirN/thisiswhatiwantonlyfirstsevencharacters"
start_index = st.rfind('/') + 1
end_index = start_index +7 
print st[start_index:end_index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rfind`, r stands for right, meaning it will start looking at the string right to left.

```
i = st.rfind('/')
st[i + 1: i + 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
st = "../dir1/dir2/dirN/thisiswhatiwantonlyfirstsevencharacters"
slashes = st.split('/')
print(slashes)
print(slashes[-1:][0][:7])
```

**Output**

```
['..', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dirN', 'thisiswhatiwantonlyfirstsevencharacters']
thisisw
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with path string you can use [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) and [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

```
import os
os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(st))[:7]
```